# Не создается модель Vosk

Tags: python-3.x, vosk

Когда писал голосовой ассистент вышла ошибка о том что не создается модель для VoskApi ( делал все на Python ), у меня модель в нужной папке и в нужной директории хотя пишет что ее нет.Вот код на python:

```
import vosk
import sys
import sounddevice as sd
import queue
import json

model = vosk.Model("model/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
samplerate = 16000
device = 1

q = queue.Queue()


def q_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(bytes(indata))


def listen(callback):
    with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize=8000, device=device, dtype='int16',
                           channels=1, callback=q_callback):

        rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)
        while True:
            data = q.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                callback(json.loads(rec.Result())["text"])
```

Текст в консоли:

```
ERROR (VoskAPI:Model():model.cc:122) Folder 'model/vosk-model-ru-0.22' does not contain model files. Make sure you specified the model path properly in Model constructor. If you are not sure about relative path, use absolute path specification.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abbaslutvaliyev/PycharmProjects/Arzu_Voise_Assistant/plugins/stt.py", line 7, in <module>
    model = vosk.Model("model/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
  File "/Users/abbaslutvaliyev/PycharmProjects/Arzu_Voise_Assistant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 53, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь к модели. Папка, в которой лежит ваш скрипт, и текущий каталог выполняемого скрипта не обязательно совпадают. Так что модель, возможно, ищется скриптом не в той папке, в какой вы думаете.

Answer (score 0):

```
model = vosk.Model(r"model/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
```

Comment: И зачем тут raw string, на что она тут влияет?